# PHP MySQL insert query not working and not displaying any error messages

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert-update

I have verified that that the post method is actually working using an echo to display the variables, but when I use the Insert query below it does not add the row.

Do you have any ideas?

```
// 1. Create a DB connection
$connection =  mysql_connect("localhost","root","P@ssword");

if(!$connection){
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());    
}

$menu_name = $_POST['menu_name'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$visible = $_POST['visible'];

$query = "INSERT INTO subjects (menu_name, position, visible) VALUES ('{$menu_name}', {$position}, {$visible})";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if ($result){
    header("Location:staff.php");
    exit;
} else {
echo "<p> There was an error when creating the
subject </p>";
"<p>". mysql_error()."</p>" ;

  }

mysql_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 2):

Confusing code o.O!. Been a long time since my code looked like this. So it was hard to figure out, lol. But, when it comes to mysql errors - when something is not providing me an error properly (when debugging that looks like this) - I read line by line. I then echo the query, and test it with mysqladmin or other sql tool. I also would run 
$query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
on the same line for quick debugging.

### Notable Issues

a) switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to be ready for future PHP changes. Get familiar with mysqli if you like mysql.

1. You didn't select a database. [mysql_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)
2. *Important* It's post data - which means, you really need to filter the information. To allow the entering of anything into a database using an insert, without escaping dangerous characters - you're leaving a lot to play with ;). Even, if you're the only one entering the information
   I changed a bit below. You have '{$menu_name}' with the single quotes, but {$position} and {$visible} without the single quotes - inconsistent is confusing when you go back months later.

Why is ('{$menu_name}', {$position}, {$visible}) not ('{$menu_name}', '{$position}', '{$visible}') ? instead.

### More Organized

```
<?
$host = "localhost"; // hostname
$user = "root"; // username
$pass = "P@ssword"; // password
$db = ""; // database name

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Database connection failed: ".mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db($db,$connection) or die("DB Selection Error: ".mysql_error());

$menu_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['menu_name']);
$position = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['position']);
$visible = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['visible']);

$query = "INSERT INTO `subjects` (`menu_name`, `position`, `visible`) VALUES ('{$menu_name}', '{$position}', '{$visible}')";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result){ // I would usually use mysql_insert_id as a validation from auto_increment tables.
    header("Location:staff.php");
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p> There was an error when creating the subject </p>
    <p>". mysql_error()."</p>" ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't select a database.

```
<?php
// 1. CReate a DB connection
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","P@ssword");
if(!$connection){
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }

mysql_select_db("DB_NAME", $connection);

?>
```

Comment: You could also use `INSERT INTO db_name.subject (field, field) VALUES (value, value);` without using `mysql_select_db()`

Answer (score 0):

Did you note your values `('{$menu_name}', {$position}, {$visible})`, they should all be quoted like `('{$menu_name}', '{$position}', '{$visible}')`.